# integration of both sides of differential equation (logistic equation with harvesting)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution for the differential equation:

$$ \frac{dY}{dt} = 2Y\left(1-\frac{Y}{200}\right)-H $$

where $H$ is a constant. This differential equation is supposed to describe a logistic function that displays exponential behaviour. Can someone please separate variables, integrate step by step and explain how to get "$e$" into the general solution?

Also, how would I go about using Euler's method to predict $Y$ if $H$ is set to $50$ and I have initial condition $Y(0)=100$?

Comment: Yes. H would be the harvesting amount (rate out), while 2Y(1-Y/200) is the growth rate (rate in).

Comment: I should probably mention that this differential equation is known a a logistic equation that follows the form dy/dt=ry(1-y/K)-H, where y=population, r= proportionality constant of growth, K= carrying capacity and H is constant (harvest).

Answer (score 1):

I will map it out, but you need to show some effort.

**Hint 1:**

We are given:

$$ \frac{dY}{dt} = 2Y\left(1-\frac{Y}{200}\right)-H $$

We can use Separation of Variables, which yields the integration problem:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{2Y\left(1-\frac{Y}{200}\right)-H}~dY = \int ~dt$$

**Hint 2:**

We have $H = 50$, so our system becomes:

$$\frac{dY}{dt} = 2Y\left(1-\frac{Y}{200}\right)-50$$

We can use Separation of Variables, which yields the integration problem:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{2Y\left(1-\frac{Y}{200}\right)-50}~dY = \int ~dt$$

After you find $Y(t)$, substitute in the initial condition $y(0) = 100$ and find $c$.

**Hint 3:**

For Euler's method, we have:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = f(t, y), a \le t \le b, y(a) = \alpha$$

Using Euler's Method, we get the iteration:

$$w_0 = \alpha, w_{i+1} = w_i + h f(t_i, w_i)$$

For this problem, lets choose (since you did not specify), $0 \le t \le 1 \implies h = \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1-0}{10} = 0.1$, so we have:

$$w_0 = 100, w_1 = w_0 + h f(t_0, w_0) = 100 + 0.1\left(2w_0\left(1-\dfrac{w_0}{200}\right)\right) - 50 = 105$$

Continue this process up to $w_{10}$ and then compare this to the result you obtain from the **Hint 2** solution.